# What causes Window.ShowDialog slow in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, showdialog

I'm working on a complex WPF application, and sometimes the simple `Window.ShowDialog` calls are slow. It takes around 5~10s to show the window. From profiling I see all native stuff:

[image]

It seems `PushFrameImpl` takes most of the time. What may possibly cause that? How can I improve it?

Comment: What's going on on release build without debugger?

Comment: It is release build without debugger.

Comment: Also, telerik..., try to turn animation off - AnimationManager.IsGlobalAnimationEnabled = false;